# Isolated LAN and WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I have ZTE F660 wireless router. My PC, laptop and smartphone are connected to the router thru Wi-Fi and they can see/ping each other. I have another PC hooked up to the router using Ethernet cable. Any of the devices connected to the WiFi cannot ping or see that hard wired PC and neither can it. I get "Destination host unreachable" message every time i try to ping it. It seems like LAN ports are isolated from the WiFi. Is there a way to make them see each other ?

SSID isolation is turned off. DHCP is working correctly, both devices are within same IP ranges and also MAC filtering is turned off

Comment: I spent about a hour on this router and it does not appear to have a wireless isolation setting. Sorry.

Comment: @John This feels weird. Routers aren't supposed to do that. Also there is no VLAN setting to tweak. The rest feels right enough to not be considered a problem

Comment: I am not sure. I use lots of wireless routers and Wireless Isolation is OFF by default. I cannot find any setting for your router.  I have looked a couple of times - no dice. My routers are all settable in this regard.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7YX7N9m
Have a look, Wireless Isolation is turned off. I've tried with this turned on too (just in case) but the isolation behavior is still the same 
Maybe a firmware update could fix this ? Or the only option would be to buy a new router..

Comment: You can try a firmware update, but that would be strange. Firmware does not usually cause this issue. So yes, it appears you need to replace the router.

Comment: Hi, anyone found solution for this.? I have stil issue with this, and can't buy new router

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

Just connect the wired one to LAN [2-4]  (didn't get it to work connected to LAN 1) Be sure that in Network/LAN/DHCP Port Service/ you get the same DHCP mode for LAN and SSID1.

Answer (score 0):

I also resolved the problem with:

- "Network / WLAN Radio2.4G / Basic / Enable Isolation" unticked (also for "WLAN Radio5G") ;
- "Network / LAN / DHCP Port Service / Dhcp Mode": Lan for the SSID you use.

I do not use the default LAN configuration (not 192.168.1.0/24), and without the "DHCP mode to LAN", I did not have access to Internet from my wireless devices. With "DHCP mode to LAN", I get access to Internet AND I am able to ping between wired and wireless devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my F680. The solution was a firmware upgrade, which fixed this bug.
I couldn't find the firmware anywhere online, so I reached out to the ISP which provided the router and they installed it remotely.

Hope this helps somebody else to avoid hours of trial-and-error.